# Run shell scripts on windows partition

Tags: partitioning, bash, permissions

I have a windows partition mounted in linux (setup with pysdm) with following options:

```
nls=iso8859-1,umask=000,gid=users,user,uid=my_user
```

I can access the data on the partition, write/read files, but when I try to run a shell script I get `permission denied`. The script has:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 my_user users 8419 Aug 11 14:06 test.sh
```

How can I please setup the partition so that I can read/write files (like now) and run scripts under my user as well as my cron/anacron jobs also being able to run commands writing to this windows partition? (i.e. full extent of functionality as my native linux partition?)

Thank you!

Comment: Convert the filesystem to ext4. Or boot up windows and use windows equivalent versions of your scripts. Or run the scripts from another partition that is ext4.  Directly of an NTFS partition? ... nope ...

Comment: @Rinzwind I think it is actually possible; see the question I VTCed it as a dupe of